# Ansible in Docker container refuses to communicate with other Docker container

Tags: docker, ansible, devops

I am currently facing a problem where my ping module I defined in my playbook.yml file refuses to connect to a different docker container. The Ansible environment is setup in a Docker container as well. The Docker service I am trying to do a ping to is called "postgres_container". The weird thing is, if I do a ping from within the ansible container with the command "ping postgres_container" it succesfully connects and stays connected. However, If I try to run the command from within my playbook.yml file, it fails.

my hosts file:

```
[database]
postgres_container
```

my playbook.yml file:

```
---
- hosts: database
  tasks:
    - name: test connection
  ping:
```

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Did you read the documentation? _This is NOT ICMP ping, this is just a trivial test module that requires Python on the remote-node._ https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/ping_module.html#synopsis. So there are plenty of reason this could happen: python not installed, SSH not running on your postgres container (which is mostly likely the case), ... If you want to know more about the failure, read the error message. And you can also try running the playbook with `-vvvv` to have it extra verbose

Comment: No I did not read it that thoroughly, I expected it to work out of the box honestly. It seems like I need to install ssh on the docker container in order for ansible to work. I am looking into setting up a container that allows for ssh communication

Comment: Ansible has a docker connection plugin you can use running your playbook from the host or mounting the docker socket and installing docker client and libs inside the container you use has a controller.

Answer (score 0):

It was indeed a problem where the containers did not have an SSH server running for ansible to connect to. Thanks @β.εηοιτ.βε for the solution.